# How turn off "replace url" in Pjax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, railscasts, pushstate, pjax

I use Pjax with tutorial from http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax?view=comments
I don't need change url and this coffee script code doesn't work:

> .....
>
> $("a#flag-comments").click ->
>
> > ....
> >
> > $.pjax
> >
> > > container: '[data-pjax-container-flag]',
> > >
> > > replace: false,
> > >
> > > url: '/flag_comments'
>
> ....

Any idea?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edit: Please see clime's answer below - It appears my answer is no longer correct.

---

Since the point of PJAX (pushState AJAX) is updating the url, I don't think there is a way to disable it. If updating the url isn't what your after you may just want to be using standard AJAX? (essentially use JQuery to perform an ajax get of a given path, then shove the contents in to a container of your choice)

The "replace" option  in the JQuery PJAX script simply toggles between using "replaceState" & "pushState" to update a pages url.

Sorry i couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 13):

Set **push: false** in options. In js, it would be:

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container', {push: false})
```

Answer (score 1):

it's not very good but it's working....

```
> $(document)
>>      .on 'pjax:beforeSend', ->
>>          $.url_old = window.location.pathname
>>      .on 'pjax:success', ->
>>          history.pushState(null, "", $.url_old)
```